# Clang warning on delete pointers

Tags: c++, clang

I begin to use clang to replace gcc. But when I delete[] pointers, it gives warning. But when I change, the warning disappears. Why and how to deal with that?

```cpp
int *a = new int[1];
int *b = new int[1];
delete[] a, b;
```

```
a.cpp:7:17: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    delete[] a, b;
```

```cpp
int *a = new int[1];
int *b = new int[1];
delete[] a;
delete[] b;
```

no warning.

Comment: You can't really blame GCC for missing this. Good C++ style is to put `delete` in a destructor - one `delete` per destructor. If you have two things that need to be deleted, you use two members managing one each. And often you don't need to write that `delete` yourself. E.g. `std::vector<int>` manages the `delete[]`for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete[] a, b;
```

is parsed as:

```
(delete[] a), (b);
```

Which you can really think of as:

```
delete[] a;
b;
```

In which case it is pretty clear that you're not doing much with `b`.

#### Where's the warning with GCC?

If you use `-Wall`, gcc will also warn on this since atleast 2007 (gcc 4.1.2):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:4:18: warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    4 |     delete[] a, b;
      |                  ^
Compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: `delete[](a, b)` Is this correct?

Comment: No. Just do it as two statements.

Comment: @zhaozk You can't delete multiple pointers in a single statement. `(a, b)` is equivalent to `b`, because of [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).